# takes parameters for the ID number and name in c++

Tags: c++

Your DeptstoreMember class should have the following public methods:

- A constructor that takes parameters for the ID number and name. If the ID number presented is 
  greater than 0, it should accepted; otherwise the ID number should be set to -1.
- Getters and setters for the ID, first name, and last name.
- A function called FullName() that returns a string consisting of the last name, a comma and space, then the first name.
  <sub>a DeptstoreMember with first name “Mark” and last name “Kevin” would 
  return “Kevin, Mark” from this function.</sub>
- A method called ReadData(). It takes an istream, passed by reference, as its only parameter. It reads in an integer (ID number) and first and last name, in that order. It then reads an int N, where N ranges from 0 to 10, as the number of prices already stored, followed by N doubles. All items are separated by whitepace. This method returns `true` if all data was read successfully, `false` otherwise.
- A method called DiscountedPrice() that takes a double as its parameter. It stores the original (undiscounted) price and returns that value reduced by 5% and the reward cash.
- Your class should use an array of doubles to store price information inside your class.
- Add other private data or methods as needed.

Comment: I'm *very* certain this is homework. (It's not, apparently. Read below.) Worse yet, however, is the fact that you didn't show what you've done... Around here, we prefer that you at least show what you've tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not homework
I tried to answer but I can not because I did not study this
But now I'm trying to learn from the Internet

Comment: Questions or issues about homework assignments should be discussed with the instructor or a fellow student before posting here.

Comment: So ... you're trying to get one of us to solve it for you but you don't know `c++`? It sounds to me like you won't even understand a solution if provided... ?

Comment: In your post, please clarify the exact issues you are having with the requirements.  For example, are you having issues compiling?  reading from a text file?  creating a function?

Comment: I do not know anything in the program I'm trying to learn on my own

Comment: Don't learn from the internet, apparently, it's not working well for you.  Get a good book from the StackOverflow C++ Recommended book list.  I recommend starting with a `main` program and incrementally updating with requirements.  Research "Test Driven Development" and "How to Use a Debugger".

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it one requirement at a time.

> Your DeptstoreMember class

```
class DeptstoreMember
{
};
```

> A constructor that takes parameters for the ID number and name. If the ID number presented is greater than 0, it should accepted; otherwise the ID number should be set to -1.

```
class DeptstoreMember
{
  public:  
    DeptstoreMember(int id, const std::string& name)
      : m_id(id), m_name(name)
    {
      if (m_id <= 0) m_id = -1;
    }
  private:
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;
};
```

> Getters and setters for the ID, first name, and last name.

```
class DeptstoreMember
{
  public:  
    DeptstoreMember(int id, const std::string& name)
      : m_id(id), m_name(name)
    {
      if (m_id <= 0) m_id = -1;
    }
    int get_id() const
    {
       return m_id;
    }
    int get_name() const
    {
       return m_name;
    }
    void set_id(int id)
    {
       if (id <= 0)
          m_id = -1;
       else
          m_id = id;
    }
    void set_name(const std::string& new_name)
    {
       m_name = new_name;
    }
  private:
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;
};
```

You should next, try implementing one requirement at a time.

I recommend creating a `main` program and getting it to compile.
Next, add the above code and get it to compile.
Next, implement another requirement, get it to compile.

You may want to make copies of the files before you add a new requirement.  This will give you a snapshot to fall back to if there are any new issues.

**Edit 1: The `main()` function**
I usually like to start with a small stencil for *console application*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(void)
{
  cout << "Paused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
  cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the above `main` function to work, then add little chunks of code and test them out.

If I make a new class, and it works in `main`, I *factor* it out into separate header and source files, then rebuild.

This process is repeated until all the requirements are satisfied.